# jquery countdown timer stop on zero

Tags: jquery

I'm making countdown with jquery from 5 seconds to zero, My countdown works perfectly but it goes infinitely I made if statement so If `dro` hits 0 I want timer to be stopped but don't know how to stop it, I tried clearinterval but not works any solutions ?

```
    var dro = 5;
    var saboloo = 0;
    function setup(){
        var es = $('#dro');
        dro--;
        es.html(dro);
        if(dro == 0){
            es.html(clearInterval(setup));
        }
    }
    setInterval(setup,1000);
```

```html
<h1 class="wait"><span value="5" id="dro">5</span>Seconds before the game starts</h1>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code like the setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really "clearing the interval" as you didn't even assign the `setInterval` to a variable and also you're clearing a function (`setup`).

How things should go :

- declare a variable that holds the number of the remaining seconds.
- declare another variable to hold the "interval" so we can clear it later.
- update the `span` with the remaining seconds along with decreasing the variable that is holding the number of the remaining seconds.
- if that variable has reached zero, clear the interval.

The next example illustrates what's being said :

```js
let remSec = $("#count"),
  /** referencing the "span" element **/
  countSec = 4,
  /** 
  * number of the remaining seconds. Change this per your requirements.
  * Equals to 4 as we'll have "(4 - 0) + 1" seconds to write which equals 5 (because the second number 0 is also included).
  **/
  /** the interval is assigned to "timer" variable so we'll be able to stop it later **/
  timer = setInterval(() => {
  /** if the seconds hasn't yet reached zero ==> write it the span. Else clear the interval **/
  countSec >= 0 ? remSec.text(countSec--) : clearInterval(timer); /** we're writing the seconds in the  span along with decreasing the "countSec" variable value at the same time note the "--" that means post decrement (use the variable then decrease one from its value) **/
  }, 1000); /** the function runs for every second till the interval is cleared **/
```

```html
<!-- for demo purposes, the "span" will hold the number of seconds -->
<div>countdown: <span id="count">5</span> seconds left.</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096245/redirect-to-another-page-after-10-seconds-using-javascript-and-a-form-submit/57097985#57097985) for another similar question if you want.

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reference for the interval, so it's not possible to clear it later. You're trying to clear the interval for `setup`, but this is not the interval reference. `setup` is just the function you are calling on each `interval`.

So, you can create the correct reference to `setInterval` and use it later to `clearInterval`.

Let's put it on a `variable` and call it `setupInterval`.

```
var dro = 5;
var saboloo = 0;
function setup(){
    var es = $('#dro');
    dro--;
    es.html(dro);
    if(dro == 0){
        es.html(clearInterval(setupInterval)); // clear the interval using the correct reference
    }
}
var setupInterval = setInterval(setup, 1000); // setupInterval is the reference
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```js
var dro = 5;
function setup(){
    var es = $('#dro');
    if(dro > 0){
        dro--;
        es.html(dro);
        let t = setTimeout(function(){
            setup();
        }, 1000);
    }
    else{
        es.html('game started');
    }
}
setup();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="wait"><span value="5" id="dro">5</span>Seconds before the game starts</h1>
```